# Navigating Through HTML of a website using beautiful soup on python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get to an `href` link inside of a nested `class` on a website. I am having trouble trying to select a specific products `href`.

This is my code:

```
r = requests.get('https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear-sneakers')
Page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
tester = soup.find(class_='collection_products').find(class_='collection-product').find_all('product-card__information')
print(tester)
```

However I keep getting this error when running my code:

```
tester = soup.find(class_='collection_products').find(class_='collection-pr
oduct').find_all('product-card__information')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

How do I find the href inside of an html that is nested inside multiple classes?
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJq8p.png) is a picture of the html on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSS Selector to select the `class`.

This script will find all the links under the `product-card__information` class

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE = 'https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear-sneakers'

r = requests.get('https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear-sneakers')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

# Select the class using a CSS Selector
for i in soup.select('.product-card__information'):
    # find the href under the anchor `a` tag
    print(BASE + i.a['href'])
```

Outputs

```
https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear-sneakers/products/nkcw7297-100
https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear-sneakers/products/nkcz0614-700
https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear-sneakers/products/nkcu9180-101
https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear-sneakers/products/pu37488101
https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear-sneakers/products/pu37487501
https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear-sneakers/products/pu37487401
https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear-sneakers/products/pu37487201
... and on
```

Comment: ohhh i get it. Thank you so much! I will use this for future websites i go on. God Bless!!